# Intent filter with different actions

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

What is the difference between the following `BroadcastReceiver`s:

1. `ReceiverA` with one intent filter, with two actions

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.example.somepackage.ReceiverA">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.somepackage.intent.actionA"/>
           <action android:name="com.example.somepackage.intent.actionB"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. `ReceiverB` with two intent filters, with one action each

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.example.somepackage.ReceiverB">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.somepackage.intent.actionA"/>
       </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.somepackage.intent.actionB"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

How will `ReceiverA` and `ReceiverB` be different in functionality from each other, regarding these `actionA` and `actionB`?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK in functionality, they both do the same: they are registered as listening to `actionA and actionB`.

`ReceiverA` is like:

```
 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
 intentFilter.addAction(actionA);
 intentFilter.addAction(actionB);
 registerReceiver(ReceiverA, intentFilter);
```

`ReceiverB` is like:

```
registerReceiver(ReceiverB, intentFilterActionA);
registerReceiver(ReceiverB, intentFilterActionB);
```